# How can I get Get-ADUser to display an error if user cannot be found?

Tags: powershell

I'm using a list of DisplayName to find SamAccountName and EmailAddress.
I want to export the information to a CSV file.
The problem is, when the script can't find the user, it just skips it.
I would like that when the user is not found, that it just adds a UNKNOWN line to the CSV.
How should I proceed?

Here's my code:

```
#get userlist
$USERS = Get-Content "C:\USER.txt"

#Get Aduser by displayname. test if user is found
$outusers = $users|%{
   $usr = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$_'" -Properties SamAccountName,EmailAddress 
   if([string]::isnullorempty($usr))
   {
      $UNKNOWN = New-Object -TypeName psobject
      $UNKNOWN | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SamAccountName -Value 'UNKNOWN'
      $UNKNOWN | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name EmailAddress -Value 'UNKNOWN'
      $usr = $UNKNOWN
   }
   $usr
}
#export samaccountname and emailaddress
$outusers |select SamAccountName,EmailAddress| Export-CSV -Path "C:\CSVFILE.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#get userlist
$USERS = Get-Content "C:\USER.txt"

#Get Aduser by displayname. test if user is found
$outusers = $users|%{
   $usr = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$_'" -Properties SamAccountName,EmailAddress 
   if([string]::isnullorempty($usr))
   {
      throw "Could not find user '$_'"
   }
   $usr
}
#export samaccountname and emailaddress
$outusers |select SamAccountName,EmailAddress| Export-CSV -Path "C:\CSVFILE.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Just do `if($usr) {..}`. If a user _is_ found, it will be an object, otherwise $null

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way to do it but I added the $UNKNOWN psobject so it would add it to the CSV file if user is not found.

Comment: @Theo Yes that is also correct, however, using this method is generally more secure as just having the variable also means it could return false if the variable var $false, 'false', 0 . The likelyness for this to happen is very low, however, its 25 letters, and its a good habit to have

Comment: No, that's a fallacy and I totally disagree. We **know** Get-ADUser returns either a (list of) ADUser object(s) or nothing ($null). What you are doing is overkill in that you are actually saying _let's try and stringify whatever came back and if that succeeds see if this string is an empty string or not_, while all you need here is to test for _did we get anything or not_. Use the string `IsNullOrEmpty()` method on **strings**, not on anything that hopefully has a `ToString()` method.